# Pull Movies details from Google Play to a Webpage

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, google-play

I want to show google playstore movies in a webpage, so that uses can get info about the movie and can buy any movies from my website. 
I haver read that Google does not expose any official API for this. Also tried available APIs from GitHub. Those are not working.
I dont want to read the DOM of google playstore page via cURL login and want to display it to my webpage.

Comment: I don't think google will allow you to do this..

Comment: I think you will have better luck with IMDB apis

Answer (score 0):

There is no exposed Google Play API, but if you're willing to do just a little bit of DOM parsing you can do this in a pretty straightforward way.

If you get a google playstore page, and scan it for all the IDs of the videos (so, for example, things like '/store/movies/details/The_Fault_In_Our_Stars?id=iXwnxJu4q7s'), you can then take those IDs and query the YouTube API with them, since the Google Play ID is identical to the YouTube ID. If you built a DB of which IDs went with which titles, you could then use the YouTube API to pull the relevant metadata, display them on your page, and even allow rentals through your side (by using the YouTube Player API with one of these IDs, users who haven't rented or bought will see, in the video, a little button that lets them start the rental process). Similarly, You can embed the YouTube player with these IDs to let users watch through your page as well.